# How would I create colouring such as in Splatoon?

Tags: game-mechanics, graphic-effects

For those who don't know, Splatoon is a game where you color ground with your teams, and other team tries to color more area in their color.

It looks like the whole ground is color-able, which makes every ground part (maybe not every pixel, but very big part of it) rendered every time a color is being sprayed. I would think is a big load on the GPU, but the Nintendo Wii U handles it pretty well.

[image: Two teams compete to color a map in pink and light blue.]
[image: Two teams compete to color a map in yellow and dark blue.]

My question is, how is it possible? Is there a trick behind that kind of process?

Comment: "maybe not every pixel but very big part of it" - probably vertex colouring. FYI, we don't really answer questions that speculate as to the technology that some or another game uses, since it is impossible for us to answer that with facts, only speculation.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer of course, I don't specifically ask for their implementation but trying to understand the way of handling those kind of heavy workload in a Multiplayer game.

Comment: If I am not mistaken this was originally a student project, the original source/documentation should be available somewhere(though I am not sure where exactly look for it).

Comment: Just noting two main edits I performed. I change the title, because on face value, it looked like you were asking "how does splatoon do that", when your actually asking how you would do something *like* that (which is good, as this makes your question on topic). In case users are not familiar with the game, I have added two screenshots that I think best reflect the mechanic you describe, citing fair use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine the easiest way to do this for large areas regardless of texture size / quality would be to send a colour / player index over the network, and treat it as a vertex colour at the destination. Let's say there are only 8 players / colours max, that's 2^3 thus 3 bits + the vertex position (vec3) in question would be used to send colour information - very low cost each network update. One could even optimise the position to be a rounded offset from the player position, reducing packet size even further. Obviously a key factor in this is what the vertex density is around each player (cost would increase as density increases).

Remember that if the world is based on a uniform grid, the vertex position could also be quite small - you wouldn't need floats @ 32 bits each - e.g. consisting of a 1024x1024 map would be 10+10=20 bits total for each vector position (`ivec2`).

It would be trivial to perform [Run-Length Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) on such a dataset in order to compress it even further. This would lead to a variable sized packet, but would definitely result in savings (as might any other compression; I mention RLE because it's conceptually simple).